# How to deal with multiple scripts in a single page web application

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Am new to Web development and i started an application where i have index.php with a menu and a div called #content and i load all the different pages in to the div #content using load(); I need to load the respective java script files along with the files that are being loaded in to the div #content.

Issue: Here in the HTML's that is loaded in to the div, i have some similar class names and id's so when i click on any menu item and perform some action there and go to another menu item and perform same action i get the script of previous menu item is being executed!

Is there a better way to load scripts into the div on the menu item click and on click of another menu item remove the previous scripts and load a fresh scripts from the current menu item clicked?

Script i use to load the div #content:

```
$('.nav-button').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#content').load('../scripts/loader.php');
$('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

sample1.php page i load in to the div on menu-item1 clicked:

```
<div id='datagrid'>
<input></input>
<input></input>
<input></input>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/menu-item1/data_script.js'></script>
```

sample2.php page i load in to the div on menu-item2 clicked:

```
<div id='datagrid'>
<input></input>
<input></input>
<input></input>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/menu-item2/data_script.js'></script>
```

Comment: data_script.js: The names are identical but if the contents are identical too why the hassle to load them and unload them. Just load them with index.php and use.

Comment: contents are definitely not identical. As i mentioned there are different scripts for different menu items(categories).

Answer (score 2):

Another way of loading scripts:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = src;
script.onload = callback_function;

document.getElementsById("#scriptContainer")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Regarding the removal of existing scripts:

Try loading your scripts in a certain container and when you want to replace them just clear out the container content and load your new scripts.

You could also try lazy loading using requirejs. [Example here](http://inside.godaddy.com/lazy-loading-optimal-user-experience/)

Answer (score 2):

Once a script has been loaded and executed, unless you tidy up your code by yourself, you will still have remnants of that code existing - even if you delete/remove the original script tag. The following points should help:

1. Whenever you create/import a structure in js, make sure you have coded an unimport / destroy ability.
2. Do not rely on script tags inserted via `.innerHTML` or `$().html()` - older browsers do not respect them and this can cause unexpected results - i.e. script tags being ignored, or in the case of older Internet explorer, attempted to be loaded from the wrong place.
3. Instead do as **thedev** recommends and build your script tags programmatically.
4. Obviously **#3** is tricky if you want to have each ajax'd script returning it's associated script tags.
5. So instead of returning pure HTML with your ajax request, instead return a JSON object that contains HTML and a list of script paths that need to be loaded.
6. If you make sure that each of your loaded scripts keeps all of it's methods exposed via a particularly named object, you can then remove this object the next time you load your next script.

What follows is illustrative code, there are more complicated *(and better)* ways of handling this *(i.e. avoiding storing objects on the window)*, plus the following code could be improved in many places - it should only serve to give you an idea of what you could do, and how to think about it.

Also it should be noted, when storing objects on the global `window` object you should use more unique names than `one`, `two` or `three` ;)

#### markup:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="one.html" data-namespace="one">One Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="two.html" data-namespace="two">Two Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="three.html" data-namespace="three">Three Link</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
  ...
</div>
```

#### javascript:

```
/// create a wrapping scope so that our variables can be local
/// to our internal code, but not mess around with the global space.
(function(){

  /// create a remembered lastID var that can store what item was loaded
  var lastID;

  /// an addScripts function that takes a string namespace (can be anything
  /// as long as it obeys usual javascript variable naming rules), and an
  /// array of script URIs.
  var addScripts = function(namespace, scripts){
    var s,i;
    for( i=0; i<scripts.length; i++ ){
      s = $('<script />')
            /// attach our src attribute with the right script path
            .attr('src', scripts[i])
            /// add our namespace as a class to help find script tag later
            .addClass(namespace); 
      /// add to the head of the document
      $('head').append(s);
    }
  }

  /// removeScripts works based on using the namespace we passed
  /// when adding scripts as a classname to find the script tags.
  /// remember removing the tags doesn't remove the executed code.
  var removeScripts = function(namespace){
    /// in order to tidy our code we should include a function
    /// to tidy up.
    if ( window[namespace] && window[namespace].tidyup ) {
      window[namespace].tidyup();
    }
    /// remove the tag to keep the markup neat
    $('script.'+namespace).remove();
  }

  /// a typical click handler applied to the a tags
  $('.menu a').click(function(){

    /// if we have a lastID remove what was before.
    if ( lastID ) {
      removeScripts(lastID);
    }

    /// get our useful info from the link
    var target = $('#content');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    /// grab out our "namespace" this will be used to tie the scripts
    /// together with the collection object in the loaded javascript.
    var namespace = $(this).attr('data-namespace');

    /// trigger an ajax request that fetches our json data
    /// from the server.
    $.ajax('loader.php',{dataType:'json',data:{url:url}})
      .done(function(data){
        /// once we have that data, add the html to the page
        target.html( data.html );
        /// and then add the scripts
        addScripts( id, data.scripts || [] );
      });

    /// store the last id so we know what to remove next time
    lastID = id;

  });

})();
```

#### loader.php:

```
<?php

  /// create a library of what scripts belong to what page
  $scripts = array(
    'one.html' => array('scripts/js/one.js'),
    'two.html' => array('scripts/js/two.js'),
    'three.html' => array('scripts/js/three.js'),
  );

  /// because `$_GET[url]` can be affected by outside influence
  /// make sure you check it's value before using it.
  switch( ($file = basename($_GET['url'])) ){
    case 'one.html':
    case 'two.html':
    case 'three.html':
      $json = (object) null;
      if ( file_exists($file) ) {
        $json->html = file_get_contents($file);
      }
      if ( isset($scripts[$file]) ) {
        $json->scripts = $scripts[$file];
      }
      header('content-type: application/json');
      /// json_encode should handle escaping all your html correctly
      /// so that it reaches your javascript in one correct piece.
      echo json_encode($json);
    break;
  }

?>
```

#### json (returned by the above php):

```
{
  "html": "<div class=\"random-content\">This can be anything</div>",
  "scripts": ["scripts/js/one.js"]
}
```

#### example js include - i.e. (one.js)

```
/// create our collection object named with the same namespace that
/// appears in the data-namespace attribute in the markup.
window.one = {};

window.one.someMethodThatMightBeUsedByLoadedContent = function(){
  /// this function has been kept specifically as part of the 'one'
  /// object because it needs to be globally accessible by the html
  /// that has been injected into the page. by keeping it as part
  /// of a named object, removing it is rather simple. (see tidyup).
}

window.one.tidyup = function(){
  /// this is the most simplistic way of tidying up a property. Depending
  /// on the complexity of your javascript there are other things you should
  /// keep in mind. If you have any large custom object structures it is best
  /// to traverse these structures key by key and remove each element. Things
  /// to read up on would be 'Javascript memory leaks', 'javascript closures' 
  /// and 'garbage collection'. It is also best to keep in mind you can only
  /// nullify variables i.e. `var abc; abc = null;` -- you can not `delete abc`
  /// this is not a problem for properties i.e. `obj.prop = 123;` and is why
  /// it is best to use them for code you wish to tidy up later.
  delete window.one;
}

$(function(){
  /// trigger off whatever code you need onload
  /// this construction will never been kept by the
  /// javascript runtime as it is entirely anonymous 
  /// so you don't need to be worry about tidying it up.
});
```

The above code has been manually typed so there may be errors, but it should illustrate one way of achieving a neat loading system that tidies up correctly on each load.